# What's the meaning of GW in GW-BASIC?

Tags: gw-basic

GW-Basic was my first programming language. And i never found out what the 'GW' stands for.

Comment: Me neither.  Check Wikipedia.

Comment: Which says: "There are several theories on what the initials "GW" stand for. Greg Whitten, an early Microsoft employee who developed the standards in the company's BASIC compiler line, says Bill Gates picked the name GW-BASIC. Whitten refers to it as Gee-Whiz BASIC and is unsure if Gates named the program after him"

Comment: Perhaps those who have voted to close could comment on how exactly this is off topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW-BASIC):

> There are several theories on what the
>   initials "GW" stand for. Greg Whitten,
>   an early Microsoft employee who
>   developed the standards in the
>   company's BASIC compiler line, says
>   Bill Gates picked the name GW-BASIC.
>   Whitten refers to it as Gee-Whiz BASIC
>   and is unsure if Gates named the
>   program after him. The Microsoft
>   User Manual from Microsoft Press also
>   refers to it by this name.
>   It may have also been nicknamed 
>   Gee-Whiz because it had a large 
>   number of graphics commands.
>   Other common theories as to the
>   initials' origins include "Graphics
>   and Windows", "Gates, William"
>   (Microsoft's president at the time),
>   or "Gates-Whitten" (the two main
>   designers of the program).